# Highcharts - colorByPoint does not work

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to get a Bar Chart with different bar color, I'm using the property colorByPoint, so (here my complete example: http://jsfiddle.net/n6GRZ/7/):

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        colorByPoint: true
    }
},
```

but this does not work as in Highcharts example in this:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/column-colorbypoint-true/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set plotOptions two times, remove additional one. this line:

```
//plotOptions:{bar:{dataLabels:{enabled: true}}},
```

[Modified DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n6GRZ/8/)